# MVC4 FileResult returning default View instead of file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have made a FileResult method in my Home controller that takes a FormCollection and returns a file based on the input. The method is working fine getting the data because after checking on Fiddler the Image option comes back as an image.
here is the controller method being called

```
public FileResult DownloadReport(FormCollection collection)
{
    byte[] response;
    string fileName = "";
    string contentType = "";
    string startDate = Convert.ToString(collection["hidden-start-date"]);
    string endDate = Convert.ToString(collection["hidden-end-date"]);
    string storeID = Convert.ToString(collection["hidden-store-id"]);
    string reportID = Convert.ToString(collection["hidden-report-id"]);
    string returnType = Convert.ToString(collection["hidden-return-type"]);
    DateTime dateStart = DataConversion.getDateTimeFromStringDateResponse(startDate.ToString());
    DateTime dateEnd = DataConversion.getDateTimeFromStringDateResponse(endDate.ToString());
    if (returnType == "pdf")
    {
        fileName = "report.pdf";
        contentType = "application/pdf";
    }
    if (returnType == "image")
    {
        fileName = "report.tif";
        contentType = "image/tiff";
    }
    if (returnType == "excel")
    {
        fileName = "report.xlsx";
        contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    }
    if (returnType == "word")
    {
        fileName = "report.docx";
        contentType = "application/msword";
    }

    SynchDB.User returnObject = (SynchDB.User)Session["SessionUserReturnObject"];
    response = SoapServiceController.getExportReportResponse(returnObject.AccountLogin, returnObject.AccountPassword, returnObject.CompanyID, Convert.ToInt64(storeID), 0, returnObject.ID, Convert.ToInt64(reportID), dateStart, dateEnd, returnType);
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
    return File(response, contentType);
}
```

The form that calls the method looks like this and it is located in the _Layout.cshtml file

```
<form id="form-content-type" method="post" action="@Url.Action("DownloadReport","Home")">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-report-id" name="hidden-report-id" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-store-id" name="hidden-store-id" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-start-date" name="hidden-start-date" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-end-date" name="hidden-end-date" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-return-type" name="hidden-return-type" />
</form>
```

the javascript that calls the method looks like this

```
downloadReport: function () {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $('#hidden-report-id').val(storage.readValue('reportID'));
    $('#hidden-store-id').val(storage.readValue('storeID'));
    $('#hidden-start-date').val(storage.readValue('startDate'));
    $('#hidden-end-date').val(storage.readValue('endDate'));
    $('#hidden-return-type').val(storage.readValue('returnType'));

    $('#form-content-type').submit();
}
```

and

```
$('#pdf-download-button').click(function () {
                $('#downloadPopup').popup('close');
                storage.storeValue("returnType", "pdf");

                DataAccess.downloadReport();
            })
```

Every time the method is called it returns to the default view which is the default route for the home controller rather than return the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks

Comment: Try adding `enctype` attribute to form?

Comment: @Akshay any reason why that would be useful?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expect to happen as result of POST request that returns non-HTML file?

Comment: I expect for the file to be downloaded to the users computer. I have created get methods that return a pdf to the user's download folder using a stream that i return as a file but when I try this method to return a file using a post I get this problem

Comment: When you are using `File` method you don't need to append any headers. Try to remove `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);`  and change a return statement to `return File(response, contentType, fileName);`

Comment: Possible you have some filter or authorize atttributes on action, which do redirect